# Is there any Jersey client setting that would allow resending of cookies with a redirect?

Tags: java, cookies, jersey-client

I am using Jersey 2.17. I want to implement the following scenario on client side:

1. my Jersey client sends a request to a certain URL;
2. the server will return me a HTTP 301 with a `Set-Cookie: abc=def` header (this is given, we don't have to worry about it);
3. my Jersey client follows the redirect;
4. my Jersey client sets the `abc=def` cookie in the second request (to the redirect target).

Redirection works fine, so step 3 is not a concern.
What I don't know is if the cookie handling is possible, as I need it. Does anybody know for sure?

Comment: What's the domain of the cookie you want to carry through? Is it always the same domain as the destination of the redirect?

Comment: you mean jsersey won't set the cookie in the 2nd request? really?

Comment: @MattBall, let's assume for now it's the same. This is what I'm interested in, even if an answer for both cases would be great ;)

Comment: If you are using a Java based client, then you have the freedom to do it, but on a browser it will be restricted

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie domain is the same as the redirected URL's domain, then the cookie does not need to be sent again, so long as the client accepts and respects the first `Set-Cookie`.

If the domains are not the same, this sounds like a security risk: cookies are deliberately scoped to a specific domain (or set of domains) and to expose a cookie outside of that would risk leaking potentially-sensitive information. So cookies *should not* be re-transmitted on a redirect across domains.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I think I have to clarify one small aspect: the cookie is not contained in the initial request. It is supposed to be set by the first HTTP response (301) and sent by Jersey client along with the second request (to the redirect target).

Comment: You wrote: "so long as the client accepts and respects the first Set-Cookie". This is exactly my question: is Jersey client able to respect cookies?

Comment: @AndreiNicusan - I bet it does. Have you tested it?